# Self Consistent Integral Equation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, analytic-functions

I have the following self-consistent integral equation

\begin{equation}
       f(x) = \int_{0}^{1-x}\frac{f(y)}{\sqrt{h^{2} + (f(y))^{2}}}dy,
\end{equation}
where $h$ is a real-valued constant.

I wish to find the real-valued function $f(x)$ over the domain $x \in [0,1]$ which satisfies this.

There is always the trivial solution $f(x) = 0$ for $h \neq 0$ but from my numerical calculations I believe that for $-2/3 \lessapprox  h \lessapprox 2/3$ there exists a non-trivial function $f(x)$ that is continuous over the domain $x \in [0,1]$ and satisfies the above equation.

I was wondering if anyone had an idea on how to solve this? Or whether there exists some closed form analytical solution here.

Note I believe (correct me if wrong) this is equivalent to finding the non-trivial solution of the differential equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{df(x)}{dx} =-\frac{f(1-x)}{\sqrt{h^{2} + (f(1-x))^{2}}}
\end{equation}

over the domain $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: You should have an extra negative sign in your derivative, I've edited this

Comment: See the "Leibniz integral rule"

Comment: Ah okay thanks for pointing that out and editing. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I’m not well-versed in ODEs. This seems very difficult

Comment: Yes it is nasty. I have played around with it but not much success.